# PHP mysql can't insert database and error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post, syntax-error

Need help here...

I receive an error code saying...

```
SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''students' (Lastname, Firstname, Middleinitial, Course, Year, Section, Studentnu' at line 1
```

by the way, i put add function in php using these codes...

```
$Lastname = $_POST['Lastname'];
$Firstname = $_POST['Firstname'];
$Middleinitial = $_POST['Middleinitial'];
$Course = $_POST['Course'];
$Year = $_POST['Year'];
$Section = $_POST['Section'];
$Studentnumber = $_POST['Studentnumber'];
$Violation = $_POST['Violation'];
$Punishment = $_POST['Punishment'];
$Violationdate = $_POST['Violationdate'];
$Punishmentstartdate = $_POST['Punishmentstartdate'];
$CSlength = $_POST['CSlength'];
$Add = $_POST['add'];

$records = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('records', $records);

$sql = ("INSERT INTO 'students' (Lastname, Firstname, Middleinitial, Course, Year, Section, Studentnumber, Violation, Punishment, Violationdate, Punishmentstartdate, CSlength) VALUES('$Lastname', '$Firstname', '$Middleinitial', '$Course', '$Year', '$Section', '$Studentnumber', '$Violation', '$Punishment', '$Violationdate', '$Punishmentstartdate', '$CSlength')");

$result = mysql_query($sql, $records);

if (!$result) 
die("SQL Error: ".mysql_error());

echo "Success";
```

thanks for the answer.... :))

Comment: Look into `SQL Injection`, you code is very vulnerable to an attack

Comment: When you not sure if query is working or not, dump the query string into the browser, copy-paste it into the SQL editor and run it in the editor. Easy to debug

Comment: Also look into PDO/MySQLi. Prepared statements will make this many variables easy to insert.

Comment: @Andrew how can i do that? can you give me an example. i'd love to finish this project. but im stuck here. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to modify you code like this!

```
$Lastname = $_POST['Lastname'];
$Firstname = $_POST['Firstname'];
$Middleinitial = $_POST['Middleinitial'];
$Course = $_POST['Course'];
$Year = $_POST['Year'];
$Section = $_POST['Section'];
$Studentnumber = $_POST['Studentnumber'];
$Violation = $_POST['Violation'];
$Punishment = $_POST['Punishment'];
$Violationdate = $_POST['Violationdate'];
$Punishmentstartdate = $_POST['Punishmentstartdate'];
$CSlength = $_POST['CSlength'];
$Add = $_POST['add'];

$records = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('records', $records);

$sql = "INSERT INTO students (Lastname, Firstname, Middleinitial, Course, Year, Section, Studentnumber, Violation, Punishment, Violationdate, Punishmentstartdate, CSlength) VALUES('$Lastname', '$Firstname', '$Middleinitial', '$Course', '$Year', '$Section', '$Studentnumber', '$Violation', '$Punishment', '$Violationdate', '$Punishmentstartdate', '$CSlength')";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $records);

if (!$result) 
die("SQL Error: ".mysql_error());

echo "Success";
```

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the quotes around `students`. Either use ticks or nothing at all:

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO `students` (Lastname, Firstname, Middleinitial, Course, Year, Section, Studentnumber, Violation, Punishment, Violationdate, Punishmentstartdate, CSlength) VALUES('$Lastname', '$Firstname', '$Middleinitial', '$Course', '$Year', '$Section', '$Studentnumber', '$Violation', '$Punishment', '$Violationdate', '$Punishmentstartdate', '$CSlength')");
```

FYI, you are wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174).

Comment: im not very familiar with that. im a begginer. so what i suppose to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$Lastname = $_POST['Lastname'];
$Firstname = $_POST['Firstname'];
$Middleinitial = $_POST['Middleinitial'];
$Course = $_POST['Course'];
$Year = $_POST['Year'];
$Section = $_POST['Section'];
$Studentnumber = $_POST['Studentnumber'];
$Violation = $_POST['Violation'];
$Punishment = $_POST['Punishment'];
$Violationdate = $_POST['Violationdate'];
$Punishmentstartdate = $_POST['Punishmentstartdate'];
$CSlength = $_POST['CSlength'];
$Add = $_POST['add'];

 $records = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());

 mysql_select_db('records', $records);


$sql = ("INSERT INTO students (Lastname, Firstname, Middleinitial, Course, Year, Section, Studentnumber, Violation, Punishment, Violationdate, Punishmentstartdate, CSlength) VALUES('$Lastname', '$Firstname', '$Middleinitial', '$Course', '$Year', '$Section', '$Studentnumber', '$Violation', '$Punishment', '$Violationdate', '$Punishmentstartdate', '$CSlength')");


  $result = mysql_query($sql, $records);

  if (!$result) 
  die("SQL Error: ".mysql_error());

  echo "Success";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets around the INSERT statement as well as put the table and column names inside the backtick, change it as below

$sql = `` "INSERT INTO `students` (`Lastname`, `Firstname`, `Middleinitial`, `Course`, `Year`, `Section`, `Studentnumber`, `Violation`, `Punishment`, `Violationdate`, `Punishmentstartdate`, `CSlength`) VALUES('$Lastname', '$Firstname', '$Middleinitial', '$Course', '$Year', '$Section', '$Studentnumber', '$Violation', '$Punishment', '$Violationdate', '$Punishmentstartdate', '$CSlength')" ``;

Since your code is too much vulnerable to SQL injection, it is better to use mysql prepared statements.Use MySQLi or PDO class to achieve it.